# Short hand if statement always returning true

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a drop down menu which lists out groups. Each group contains a property (boolean) that determines if the groups owner is a user or another group

If the groups owner is a user, I get the groups ownerID and compare that with an array of users to determine which user matches that ID and set that user as the `selectedOwner`. However, if the groups owner is a group, I'll try to loop through all my groups to find the match and set that group as `selectedOwner`

This is my controller function:

```
$scope.groupOwner = function (){
    var temp = $scope.selectedGroup.ownerIsUser ? $scope.users : $scope.groups;
    var index = temp.length; 
    console.dir(temp);
    while(index--){
        if($scope.selectedGroup.owner === temp[index].id){
            $scope.selectedOwner = temp[index];
            console.log($scope.selectedOwner);
            break;
        };
    };      
};
```

Whenever the dropdown is changed it called `groupOwner` which checked the `selectedUser.ownerIsUser` property to determine which array I should be looking into, `users` or `groups`.

However, the temp variable is always returning true, no matter what the selectedGroup owner property is set to.

This is what the objects look like:

```
User = { 
name: Demo Administrator,
id: 90,
domain: i:0#.w|itun\demoadmin_compulite,
email: ,
isAdmin: False
 }

selectedGroup =  { 
name: Test Group,
id: 10,
description: ,
owner: 88,
ownerIsUser: False
 }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="topRow">
    <label for="entityDropDown">Select a Group:</label>
    <select id="entityDropDown" ng-model="selectedGroup" ng-options="group as group.name for group in groups" ng-change="getGroupInfo(selectedGroup)"></select>
    <div class="delGroupBtn"><a>&#10006;</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

Console output of object:

```
Object {name: "Test Group 4", id: "117", description: "", owner: "71", ownerIsUser: "False"…}
description: ""
id: "117"
name: "Test Group 4"
owner: "71"
ownerIsUser: "False"
__proto__: Object
```

**Solved:**

```
$scope.groupOwner = function (){
    //object stores string not booleans
    var isUser = $scope.selectedGroup.ownerIsUser === "True"? true : false;  
    var owner = isUser ? $scope.user : $scope.group;
    var index = owner.length; 
    console.dir(owner);
    while(index--){
        if($scope.selectedGroup.owner === owner[index].id){
            $scope.selectedOwner = owner[index];
            console.log($scope.selectedOwner);
            break;
        };
    };      
};
```

Comment: No offense, but shouldn't Batman know these kinds of things if he has any hope of saving Gotham? ... :P

Comment: Please add how are you setting the selectedGroup to scope from HTML.

Comment: Actually I think I figured it out. False should be "false". Which is dumb since that's how the xml returns the value. Can anyone confirm whether this is likely the problem? JS is case sensitive right.

Comment: Can you post your html code too? I wonder whether the value of `$scope.selectedGroup.ownerIsUser` is boolean or a String

Comment: Is that data (`User` and `selectedGroup`) supposed to be JavaScript or JSON? Because it's neither.

Comment: It's javascript. I just copied it from Batarang which formats it strangely in the console but it's definitely a javascript object.

Comment: Updated OP with console output. It looks like the property might be a string and not a boolean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable is "False" and not boolean false."False" is a string, which always evaluates as true.

```
var temp = $scope.selectedGroup.ownerIsUser ? $scope.users : $scope.groups;
```

Will always set `temp = $scope.users`

Some javascript console testing example :

```
> a = "False"
> "False"
> b = false
> false
> testValue = a ? 1 : 2;
> 1
> testValue = b ? 1 : 2;
2
```

Comment: Yea I slowing started realizing the object didn't contain a boolean like I thought it was. I've added another if statement to check the string and return true or false. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this object is not defined currectly

```
selectedGroup:  { 
name: Test Group,
id: 10,
description: ,
owner: 88,
ownerIsUser: False
}
```

It should be defined with all variable values

```
selectedGroup:  { 
name: Test_Group, // or 'Test Group'
id: 10,
description: '',
owner: 88,
ownerIsUser: false
}
```

Comment: Yea I think the property i'm evaluating is a string from what i'm seeing in the console. That's likely why I'm not getting the expected result. When I hardcore false or true, the if statement works fine.